# fadeIn Element just once in a session

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I have a function:

```
function loremIpsum() {
$('.element').fadeIn()
}
```

to show a hidden Element - The issue is, that a user can go back with a second button and call the loremIpsum() function again, but the function should be called just once.
Can I limit that in someway ? I couldn't find a Post for that here.

I tried this:

```
function loremIpsum() {
    var executed = false;
    return function() {
        if (!executed) {
            executed = true;
            $('.element').fadeOut()

        }
    }
}
```

But that didn't work

Comment: Save a flag to [Window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function loremIpsum() {
    loremIpsum= function() {};
    $('.element').fadeIn()
}
```

Did work - nevermind then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sessionStorage` to keep track of `executed` boolean value for the session.

```js
function loremIpsum() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('executed', true);
    $('.element').fadeIn();
}
```

And in the caller, you can check:

```js
if (!(sessionStorage.getItem('executed') === "true")) { //since sessionStorage stores items as strings
    loremIpsum();
}
```